# Add a Context Action to the default options for Flutter in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I've done some digging and came up empty. Using Android Studio with flutter, the standard context actions are great...add padding, container, column, row etc.

I have a couple widgets that I'm going to be using a lot, and I was wondering if I can add them to my context actions. Some are standard Flutter widgets, some are custom to this project. Couldn't figure out where.

Comment: did you find out solution? I am also trying to find it. @jbryanh

Comment: No, didn't find anything.

Comment: @jbryanh did you find any solution yet, I'm also in dire need of this

Comment: Nope, just keep upvoting the question.